# Delete a file from firebase storage using download url with Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of profiles in my Firestore db and a field named "profilePicture" with a downloadUrl as the value.

Im using cloud functions and been trying for a long time to figure out how to delete the profilePicture when the profile is deleted.

I know how to create a trigger when the profile is deleted and get the profile picture downloadUrl, but how do I delete the file from storage with only the downloadUrl?

Comment: How did you generate the download URL?

Comment: @DougStevenson I just retrieved it from the meta data when storing the picture on the device using swift.

Comment: [This is link answer the Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66704671/13082664)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My understanding is that the [node SDK for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.4.x/) can't convert HTTP URLs into file paths within a storage bucket.  Instead, you should be storing the file path along with the download URL in document.  This will make it possible for to build a File object that can be used to delete the image when it's time to do so.

Comment: That what I was thinking. I'm gonna go with your solution so I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: but you can extract path file from url ,see my answer below

Comment: @MahmoudAbuElheja Firebase Storage does not guarantee the format of that URL.  If you depend on its format, your code could break in the future.  That's a risk you will have to take.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for notice me , but are you sure from that  because i tested this approach   on multi file on storage and work fine !  ,  so what the case maybe not work with this ?

Comment: @MahmoudAbuElheja Just because something *works today*, that doesn't mean in will *work in the future*.  There is no documentation explaining the format of the URL, which implies that the Firebase team might feel the need to change it some day.

Answer (score 15):

The [firebase storage documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Storage#refFromURL) provides a method `refFromURL(url)` that can be used on a `Storage` instance. It states the `url` argument can be:

> A URL in the form:
>
> 1) a gs:// URL, for example gs://bucket/files/image.png
>
> 2) a download URL taken from object metadata.

Based (2) above, it seems like an HTTP URL should also work. However it probably is better practise to store a path string, as the tokens on the HTTP URLs can get rotated by Firebase.

Answer (score 10):

for `admin.storage.Storage` is no build in method for get reference from url for storage

**but you can extract file path from URL ,by remove **baseUrl** and do some code replace on URL**

im create method for this task to accept url from storage project and return path

```
function getPathStorageFromUrl(url:String){

    const baseUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-80505.appspot.com/o/";

    let imagePath:string = url.replace(baseUrl,"");

    const indexOfEndPath = imagePath.indexOf("?");

    imagePath = imagePath.substring(0,indexOfEndPath);
    
     imagePath = imagePath.replace("%2F","/");
    
 
    return imagePath;
}
```

> **NOTE :** You must replace `baseUrl` for every project, you can find it by open any image in you storage , and copy it from URL in browser from start to end of last slash '/'

Ex :

```
Some image link on my storage : 
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-80505.appspot.com/o/RequestsScreenshot%2F-M6CA-2bG2aP_WwOF-dR__1i5056O335?alt=media&token=d000fab7

the base URL will be 
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-80505.appspot.com/o/
```

now after get path call file to delete it from storage

```
const storage = admin.storage();

const imagePath:string = getPathStorageFromUrl(obj.imageUrl);

storage.bucket().file(imagePath).delete().catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

> **NOTE** : There is no documentation explaining the format of the URL,
> which implies that the Firebase team might feel the need to change it
> some day , mean maybe will not work in the future if format is change.

Answer (score 9):

In Angular I use this to delete file from Cloud Firestore by downloadURL

```
constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) {}

onDeleteAttachment(downloadURL: string) {
  this.storage.storage.refFromURL(downloadURL).delete();
}
```

Comment: There's a similar method in Kotlin storageRef.getReferenceFromUrl(url) your answer helped me find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mahmoud's answer need a little edit .. it works tho ..  He is doing the replacements wrongly and might not work if you have nested directories or spaced filenames in your storage

```js
getPathStorageFromUrl(url:String){

        const baseUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-80505.appspot.com/o/";
    
        let imagePath:string = url.replace(baseUrl,"");
    
        const indexOfEndPath = imagePath.indexOf("?");
    
        imagePath = imagePath.substring(0,indexOfEndPath);
        
        imagePath = imagePath.replace(/%2F/g,"/");
        
        imagePath = imagePath.replace(/%20/g," ");
     
        return imagePath;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**confing.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "XXXX",
            authDomain: "XXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://XXXX-app-web.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "XXXX",
            storageBucket: "XXXX-app-web.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "XXXXXX",
            appId: "1:XXX:web:XXXX",
            measurementId: "G-XXXX"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
export const storageRef = firebase.storage();

export default firebase;
```

**Button.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {firestore,storageRef} from './Config';

function removeFile(id,downloadUrl) {
  const storageRefa = storageRef.refFromURL(downloadUrl);

  storageRefa.delete().then(() => {
    firestore.collection("All_Files").doc(id).delete().then((response) => {
      console.log('delete response', response)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('delete error', error)
    })
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('delete error', error)
  });
}
export default function MediaCard(props) {
  return (
    <>
           <Button
              onClick={() =>{
                removeFile(props.ID,props.downloadUrl)
              }}
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
          >
            Delete
          </Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: refFromURL exists on the Web SDK, not in the cloud functions SDKs, which the question asks.